# Is there commands regarded to scrlayer-scrpage and modifies the chapter page?

Tags: koma-script, scrbook

Is there any commands in the scrlayer-scrpage that can modify the background of the chapter (first) page? For example, my inner contents have backgrounds like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude,openright,chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ilines]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\definecolor{color00}{HTML}{9B9B9B}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=scrheadings}
\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{contbackground}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\textareabg{%
  \tikz\fill[white](0,0)rectangle({\layerwidth},{\layerheight});}
\newcommand*\marginbg{%
  \tikz\fill[\chapterbackcolor,opacity=.05](0,-4cm)rectangle({\layerwidth-0.3cm},{\layerheight-3cm});}
\DeclareNewLayer[background,outermargin,addvoffset=-0.6cm,contents=\marginbg]{margin.bg}
\DeclareNewLayer[background,textarea,addvoffset=-5pt,addhoffset=-5pt,addwidth=10pt,addheight=10pt,contents=\textareabg]{text.bg}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{contbackground}{text.bg,margin.bg}
\makeatother
\newcommand\chapterbackcolor{}
\renewcommand\chapterbackcolor{%
  \ifcase\value{part}color00\or color01\or color02\fi}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{contbackground}
\newpagecolor{lightgray!25!white!}
\chapter{Blah...}
\end{document}
```

*Edit 1&2: changed the wording in question and a more specific MWE.*

Comment: It is not considered appropriate to **sketch** your problem and then  **sketch** an answer just because you do not really need help. At the most basic level people should be able to understand your question (as well as answers) before they run the code, right?

Comment: Yea, I understood did something not should be done. I admit that I did not think carefully to publish this question.

Comment: Well, different questions deserve different criteria. If there is a question concerning some deep deep logical bug, it is fine to leave little messages once they are enough for those who are able to solve it. But if your question targets beginners you had better add some vivid description/figures to attract them

Answer (score 1):

Default page style of the chapter pages is the `plain` style of the current pair of page styles. If this pages should have the same background as the other pages of the chapter you have to add the line

```
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{plain.contbackground}{text.bg,margin.bg}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually just two lines,

```
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{chapter}{what-styles-you-wanted}
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{chapter}
```